# C# Regex find string between two strings with newLine

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

Here is my regex: `Regex r = new Regex("start(.*?)end", RegexOptions.Multiline);`

That means I want to get the stuff between `"start"` and `"end"`. But the problem is that between start and end is a new line or `\n` and the regex doesn't return anything.

So how do I make regex find `\n`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name of the `Multiline` option is misleading, as is the one of the correct option - `Singleline`:

```
Regex r = new Regex("start(.*?)end", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

From MSDN, [RegexOptions Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx):

> Singleline - Specifies single-line mode. Changes the meaning of the dot (.) so it matches every character (instead of every character except \n).

Comment: +1 can we do something here to exclude the start and end , that is if I want to get only the values between start and end .

Answer (score 2):

Include the RegexOptions.SingleLine which means that `.` matches everything, including `\n`

```
Regex r = new Regex("start(.*?)end", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.SingleLine);
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx for more details.

Comment: Hmm all other says I sohuld use singleLine only. Does it matter if I add multiline?

Comment: In your case no, it won't make any difference either way, unless you are using ^ or $ in your regex. See the linked doc for the definition of all the enums.

Comment: What, if i have more than one start ...some text .... end pairs in my Input, and want to get them all?

Example:

start
....text i want ...
end

start
... another text i want ...
end

When i use Singleline the dot matches CR\LF but i only get one match.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Singleline** instead of *Multiline*:

```
Regex r = new Regex("start(.*?)end", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

BTW, [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) is your invaluable friend (No, I'm not connected whatsoever to the author, except for being a happy user).